# Can you identify the flying ship in this screenshot?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to identify this ship (flying ship with two side rudders and a balloon/dirigible holding it in the air).

It came from a youtube video I saw a while ago, but I don't have the video anymore so no clue what the comments said about the movie the clip was from.

[image]

The movie it's from is likely a popular one, since the original Youtube video was one of the parodies (where you mate a clip of well known movie with unrelated but popular song).

Comment: There's [a lot of airship parodies](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0388.html), incidentally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help me find a film about some dude who fell in love with a star (a literal stellar object)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190435/help-me-find-a-film-about-some-dude-who-fell-in-love-with-a-star-a-literal-stel)

Comment: FWIW, voted to leave open because this question is rather an object-id and reading both questions wouldn't lead one to think it's the sam story at stake, I think.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

That's Captain Shakespeare's [sky-ship](https://youtu.be/VfYBKDyF-Dk?t=1m29s) (The Perdita) from the film [Stardust](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0486655/).

[image]

Comment: 8 mins? That's really slow man. A let down. You should delete this answer in shame. Also, can I have your rep?

Comment: @Möoz - I was [otherwise engaged](http://assets.platform.controlshiftlabs.com/petitions/images/7791/open_graph/occupied_toilet.jpg?1472013100)