# Film about some dude who fell in love with a star (a literal stellar object)

Tags: story-identification, movie

Yes, the plot is pretty weird. There is this "star" (whose incarnation is a woman dressed in white) and some random guy who falls in love with her. There's the arc of "if you cross a specific border you'll die" which applies to our lady "star". Well, I also remember that they have some kind of a tubular case, and when one opens it, lightning files out.

I watched the film somewhere around 2010, it's in English and when I try to remember it, I get the vibe of a mediocre Hollywood fantasy romance.

Comment: Somehow, I cannot explain, this reminded me of BRODYQUEST which I have not seen since it was on Letterman. Could that be it?

Comment: Related: In the Addams Family Musical, Uncle Fester falls in love with the moon.

Comment: @Willtech - Two star*fish* fall in love with Adrien Brody during [BRODYQUEST](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygI-2F8ApUM)...

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This is [*Stardust*](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stardust_(2007_film)) from 2007.

> The film follows Tristan, a young man from the fictional town of Wall. Wall is a town on the border of the magical fantasy kingdom of Stormhold. Tristan enters the magical world to collect a fallen star to give to his crush Victoria, in return for her hand in marriage. He collects the star who, to his surprise, is a woman named Yvaine. Witches and the Princes of Stormhold are also hunting for Yvaine. Meanwhile, Tristan tries to get her back to Wall with him before Victoria's birthday, the deadline of her offer.

The wall you've mentioned would indeed kill her (she'd turn into a meteorite) and the "tube" contained harvested lightning that was collected by their erstwhile host Captain Shakespeare (Yarrr!).

Comment: De Niro is great in that one, with a cheeky low-profile role by Henry Cavill. What a great film, for the acting alone.

Comment: The OP should read the book instead. Very much not mediocre. The film though... oh dear...

Comment: @Graham - The book was good. The film was great.

Comment: I remember really liking this film. I wonder if I should rewatch it...

Comment: @DeepDeadpool - When it comes to Stardust, the answer is always a firm "yes, you should rewatch it".

Comment: Also the protagonist is pre-Daredevil Charlie Cox.

Comment: YMMV, but for me both the book and film are good.  And a great, bit ironic, role for Michelle Pfeiffer. Might wanna mention that Neil Gaiman wrote it ;-)

Comment: I think this is one the best roles I've seen De Niro in. :) He just so obviously enjoyed the role.

Answer (score 35):

This reminds me very strongly of Neil Gaiman's short novel *Stardust* (1998), which I know has been adapted for film, though I've not seen that version.

The young man crosses the wall into Fairie to retrieve a fallen star. When he finds her, he realises that she is a young woman. She cannot leave Fairie, or she would become a meteorite, what a fallen star is in our world.

Comment: There's two versions of the book, the original one ends with all the characters dead of old age except the star who stays trapped on earth as the eternal queen of Stormhold and another that's closer to the ending of the movie where her and Tristran escape the mortal realms for an eternal life in the sky.

Comment: lol this is posted after the film answer idgi

Comment: @Ash, where is the latter version of the book?

Comment: @theonlygusti. I cannot work out what you're trying to say.

Comment: @Wildcard My local library has/had both, I'll try and remember to get the ISBNs next time I'm in.

Answer (score 2):

This is not likely to be the answer to your question, but the title of this post made me think of this, so I figured I'd fill in the blank for anyone that came by here looking for alternative answers to the title question.

Ray the lightning bug in *The Princess and the Frog* falls in love with a star whom he has named Evangeline. He even sings a song about her and [ends up with her at the end of the movie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1hBn.jpg).

[*The Princess and the Frog*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0780521/) was released in 2009, though Ray is a supporting character, not the focus of the plot.